# Wait until data is fetched from database and then return android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, mongodb-query

I am writing a class in java which is going to fetch results from a MongoDB database and then return the results back to the main program. My code is as follows:

```
   public Document[] search(Document query, String databaseName, String collectionName) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Search query: " + query);
    _mongoClient.getDatabase(databaseName).getCollection(collectionName).find(query).continueWith(
            new Continuation<List<Document>, Object>() {

                @Override
                public Object then(@NonNull final Task<List<Document>> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to execute query");
                    } else {

                        if (task.getResult().size() == 0) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Query failed to return any results");
                            return null;
                        }


                        results = new Document[task.getResult().size()];
                        for (Integer i = 0; i < task.getResult().size(); i++) {
                            results[i] = task.getResult().get(i);
                            Log.i("test",  results[i].getString("username").toString());
                        }


                    }
                    return null;
                }
            });



    return results;
}
```

The issue with my code is that it doesn't wait for the code inside the method for retrieving the database to run. Instead it jumps straight to the return statement.
I have tried using AsyncTask like this:

```
    private class WaitForDB extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pd.setMessage("Please wait");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Document query = new Document("username", "a");
        _mongoClient.getDatabase("gapp").getCollection("parent").find(query).continueWith(
                new Continuation<List<Document>, Object>() {

                    @Override
                    public Object then(@NonNull final Task<List<Document>> task) throws Exception {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to execute query");
                        } else {

                            if (task.getResult().size() == 0) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Query failed to return any results");
                                return null;
                            }


                            results = new Document[task.getResult().size()];
                            for (Integer i = 0; i < task.getResult().size(); i++) {
                                results[i] = task.getResult().get(i);
                                Log.i("test",  results[i].getString("username").toString());
                            }


                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                });
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }

    }

}
```

However, this does not work either. So, I would like to know, is there a way for the program to wait until the data is retrieved from the database? And if yes, how?

I will appreciate any kind of help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code doesn't wait only because you wrote it that way. If you want to observe that, put more log statements outside of error conditions or where you are building the result list, as well as before the return statements. The result list will be built after the `return results`.

What you can do is pass the "continuation" through to the method as a parameter

```
public void search(Document query, String databaseName, String collectionName, Continuation<List<Document>, Object> continuation) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Search query: " + query);
    _mongoClient.getDatabase(databaseName)  
         .getCollection(collectionName)
         .find(query)
         .continueWith(continuation);
}   //end method
```

And that's it for that method. Do your processing elsewhere where you need the documents

For example, rather than trying to make this a blocking call for results

```
Document[] documents = search(...);
// process documents
```

You need to invoke the function, which waits for results to be received, then executes the inner callback function

```
// Do not define documents here 
search(query, database, collection, 
    new Continuation<List<Document>, Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object then(@NonNull final Task<List<Document>> task) throws Exception {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to execute query");
            } else {
                List<Document> documents = task.getResults();
                // process documents 
            } 
    });
// if you did define documents outside this, it'll still be empty
```

If you want to reduce all this code just to get an actual Document array, you need to define your own interface, but this is the most flexible working solution without extra classes

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The answer you provided makes sense, however, I am not sure where to retrieve the results from. And what should I pass as the continuation parameter?

Comment: You call `search(query, database, collection, new Continuation<List<Document>, Object>() { // get results here });` in the current place you attempted to call that method.

Comment: The problem is that I need to return the results to other classes. The way my application works is that I have a class which is dealing with all the database stuff such as deleting, searching, etc. And I need to return that results back to other classes. Is this not possible?

Comment: That's exactly what this does... It's using Callback functions. You cannot use `return` statements for asynchronous code. You pass in an implementation of an interface / abstract class

Comment: Yeah, what you say makes sense. This answers my question, thank you very much. Another question I would like to ask, which you don't have to answer, but I would be grateful if you could. Is there a way to send a query as a parameter to another method, and then get the results back in the Document array form?

Comment: You already are sending a query as a parameter to the search method. Also you are getting a `List` already. Why do you need an array?

Comment: Well, I was trying to kind of make use of encapsulation, so when the programmer calls search method, which is written inside another class, he/she will get the Document array as the results.

Comment: You could expose some other method `private String database; ... public void getDocuments(Continuation<List<Document>, Object> continuation) {  mongoClient.getDatabase(database).getCollection("documents") }` and so on... I don't see the reason for providing a generic `search()` method.

Comment: It is fine this way, again, thank you very much for your responses, I now understand how this works, and sorry for taking your time.